# REXX Choose random say command

Tags: random, command, rexx

Anyone knows how to do this?:

```
say 'something'
or 
say 'something'
or 
say 'something'
```

I want to choose randomly between these say commands. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* REXX */    
x = RANDOM(1,3)
       Select
         when x = 1 then
            say 'something'
         when x = 2 then do
            say 'something'
         Otherwise
            say 'something'
       end  /* Select */
 Pull answer .
 if answer='NO' then say 'Answer is NO.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Random](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/e04a2a01/4.4.42?DT=19921218100410) function and a [Select](http://publibfp.dhe.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/e04a2a01/3.21?DT=19921218100410) statement.

Comment: Thanks. I just made three loops.

Comment: I have another question. Is there a way to wait for input? For example I ask question and I need to receive answer in one minute.